# Adding to database and displaying in multi list box

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

Hi guys i'm trying to make an app which takes data from some tkinter entry boxes adds them to a database and also displays them in a multi list box from tktreectrl. The code I have tried to use to add things to the database was based on various online tutorials however all this is doing is adding a 0 in the last column of the database. And even if I put values into the database using DB Browser they are still not displayed in the multi list box. (Here is the full code)

```
#Import Modules
import tkinter
import TkTreectrl
import sqlite3
#Database
db = sqlite3.connect("marks.db")
cursor=db.cursor()
print("Opened Database")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS marks (Firstname, Surname, Mark)")
print("Table created")
#Variables
Surname = str()
Firstname = str()
Mark = int()
#Define Buttons
def addentry() :
   db.execute('INSERT INTO marks VALUES (?,?,?);', (Firstname,Surname,Mark))
   db.commit()
   print ("Entry Added To Database")

def deleteentry() :
   selected=listbox.get(ACTIVE)
   name=selected[0]
   db.execute('DELETE FROM marks where Firstname =?', (name))
   print ("Entry Deleted")
#Window
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("marks")
window.geometry("875x500")
#Labels
lbl_surname = tkinter.Label(window, text="Surname:", font="Arial 12 bold")
lbl_first = tkinter.Label(window, text="First-Name:", font="Arial 12 bold")
lbl_mark = tkinter.Label(window, text="Mark (Percentage):", font="Arial 12 bold")
#Entry
txt_surname = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable=Surname)
txt_first = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable=Firstname)
txt_mark = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable=Mark)
#Button
but_save = tkinter.Button(window, text="Save", command= addentry, width=10)
but_delete = tkinter.Button(window, text="Delete", command=deleteentry, width=10)
#List
listbox = TkTreectrl.MultiListbox(window)
listbox.config(columns=('Firstname', 'Surname', ' Mark'))
cursor.execute('SELECT * from marks')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    listbox.insert('end',*map(unicode,row))
#Grid
lbl_surname.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=100)
lbl_first.grid(row=0, column=0)
lbl_mark.grid(row=0, column=2)
txt_surname.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=110)
txt_first.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)
txt_mark.grid(row=1, column=2)
but_save.grid(row=0, column=3)
but_delete.grid(row=1, column=3)
listbox.grid(row=2)
#Render
window.mainloop()
```

Any Ideas
on what I've done wrong

Thanks Chris

Comment: Have you verified that `Firstname`, `Surname`, and `Mark` actually have values at the time you're doing the commit? Have you verified that `fetchall()` is actually returning a non-empty result?

Comment: It would appear that Firstname etc.. don't have values. So how would i go about making it so they day i assumed you could use the textvariable of an entry widget, but is there something else I have to do in order to retrieve the contents of the entry box?

Comment: Yes, you can use the textvariable. Without seeing your code it's impossible for me to guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The code for the entry widgets is:   txt_surname = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable=Surname) this the same for the other entries obviously just with different text variables.

Comment: Waffle, that's one extra line of code isn't helpful at all. If you want to add more code, edit the question and add a complete working program (also known as an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have added the full code into my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `textvariable` wrong. The value needs to be a special Tkinter variable such as `StringVar`. The second is that you have to use the `get` method on these variables to get the value. For example:

```
firstNameVar = tkinter.StringVar()
...
txt_first = tkinter.Entry(..., textvariable=firstNameVar)
...
Firstname = firstNameVar.get()
...
```

Comment: I'm now getting the error: File "E:/Python/Competition/Competition.py", line 16, in <module>
    FirstnameVar = tkinter.StringVar()
  File "E:\Programs\Miniconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 287, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "E:\Programs\Miniconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 215, in __init__
    self._tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: @TheEpicWaffle: you have to create the root window before you create the variables. This has been asked and answered on this site. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8762747/7432